# Ninject - Create class conditionally in .Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing here.  I am trying to use ninject to create a class.  The class accepts a single string parameter which is stored in Session of the HttpContext.  How do I pass that parameter to this class?

The class looks like:

```
public class Manager : IManager
{
    public Manager(string a) { ... }
}
```

I have a custom Dependency Resolver that looks like:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    IKernel kernel;
    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        Bind<IManager>().To<Manager>()
    }

    ...
}
```

A typical controller looks like:

```
public class ManagerController : Controller
{
    public ManagerController(IManager manager) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That the parameter is stored in the Session is relevant implementation detail and doesn't belong into the Ninject configuration.

You should create a `IManagerConfiguration` interface that has a property for each config value for the manager and a Session Store implementation for that interface. Now you can add a simple binding for them and pass the interface to the managers constructor instead of the string.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Session can't be accessed at the initial time please check the @James answer below.

Did you try using `WithConstructorArgument`.

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    IKernel kernel;
    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        Bind<IManager>()
           .To<Manager>()
           .WithConstructorArgument("a", ..)
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: How would that work?  I would have guessed that this wouldn't work since it's accessing the session at the time of creating the resolver instead of at request time.  Does the resolver get created fresh on every request?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            var copyToNew = new ConstructorArgument("isCopyToNew", IsCopyToNew);
            IParameter[] pars = new Parameter[] {  copyToNew };
            var anyViewModel = IoC.Kernel.Get<IAnyViewModel>(pars);
```

or

```
var anyViewModel=IoC.Kernel.Get<IAnyViewModel>(new ConstructorArgument("isCopyToNew",IsCopyToNew));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the Manager param from a string to `Func<string>`, then you could use WithConstructorArgument and a Func of () => HttpContext.Current.Session["foo"].ToString()

If you can't, then I would likely instead inject a IManagerFactory with a Create method that took that string parameter, and while you could do it manually by making your own factory, I'd use the ninject extension for ToFactory.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface